# Is there a way to make it so that MOUSE_DRAGGED does not fire until it moves 10 pixels JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, mouseevent, transparency

The title explains it.

So I have an application that fades to 1/2 opacity when it is not moused over and full when it is. This application is `StageStyle.TRANSPARENT` and moves around when the user drags their mouse.

I am wondering if there is a way to make it so that the mouse has to drag a certain (10) amount of pixels before the drag event is triggered?

Here is the code

```
    moveWindowTemp dragDelta = new moveWindowTemp();
    primaryScene.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, mouseEvent -> {
        dragDelta.x = primaryStage.getX() - mouseEvent.getScreenX();
        dragDelta.y = primaryStage.getY() - mouseEvent.getScreenY();
    });

    primaryScene.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED, mouseEvent -> {
        primaryStage.setX(mouseEvent.getScreenX() + dragDelta.x);
        primaryStage.setY(mouseEvent.getScreenY() + dragDelta.y);
        isBeingMoved = true;
    });
    primaryScene.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_RELEASED, mouseEvent -> {
        primaryStage.setX(mouseEvent.getScreenX() + dragDelta.x);
        primaryStage.setY(mouseEvent.getScreenY() + dragDelta.y);
        isBeingMoved = false;
    });
...
    public class moveWindowTemp {
        double x, y;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you could simply set the event as being consumed in your event filter. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/events-tutorial/filters.htm#BCFDCCEJ

Comment: This link may be more relevant: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/events-tutorial/filters.htm#BCFDCCEJ  (Same tutorial, updated to JavaFX 8)

Comment: Thanks. Don't know why Google always comes up with this old stuff first. I've updated my link above.

Comment: This seems to be what I want. I don't have access to the application for now, I will check out what you have said and if I can get it working I will mark you as correct